# Information structure in MVC 4, ASP.NET, C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I'm not all that familiar with ASP.NET, MVC 4. But I was wondering something.

After following a basic tutorial on the asp.net website for mvc 4, I learned to make a basic gridview (or table?) that was essentially bound with data from a self-created database. Which was structured from a self-created model.

When I created the controller however, it obviously linked up the self-created model with the self-created database and created view pages.

Now here comes the question. I want to build a database with only this 1 controller that can be accessed throughout the whole website.

For example, lets say I created a "Article" Controller (with having a model and the connection string already linked). Now afterwards, down in the "Views" I would have a "Article" folder with "Index", "Edit", "Delete", "Create", etc.

Now on my "Home/Index" page (previously created), I want to structure it so I can put an article on it that has been created from the Article section (controller?)(that has been saved in the database). This was not in the tutorial.

I apologize if there is a million articles on how to do this, but I wouldn't have a clue on what to type into google to answer this question.

I hope I clarified my question enough :/
cheers

Comment: Can you please share the article you are referring in the tutorial? Also I am not able to understand your questions well (Sorry for that), can you please explain it in lay man words, what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry, It's hard for me to clarify things :|

This is the article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-4.

Now after that tutorial was done, I was able to edit, create new movies in the movies view, but the edit, create,etc. options could only be accessed through the movies view. I want to be able to have another page where I can still view these movies and still have all the permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create Parent-View-Model and using it in Homepage(View)

an example:

```
public class ParentViewModel 
{
    public ArticleModel articlemodelObject { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleModel
{
    public int id { get;set; }
    public string article { get;set; }
}
```

Hope that helps :)